# Is there a brief syntax for executing a block n times in Scala?

Tags: scala

I find myself writing code like this when I want to repeat some execution n times:

```
for (i <- 1 to n) { doSomething() }
```

I'm looking for a shorter syntax like this:

```
n.times(doSomething())
```

Does something like this exist in Scala already?

**EDIT**

I thought about using Range's foreach() method, but then the block needs to take a parameter which it never uses.

```
(1 to n).foreach(ignored => doSomething())
```

Comment: Saving 5-6 characters of typing at the cost of requiring readers of your code to understand your personal DSL? I think it's a mistake.

Comment: You can minimize the ignored stuff: `1 to n foreach(_ => doSomething())`

Comment: @Paul It shouldn't be a personal DSL really.  A method called times() on numbers is very common in other languages.

Comment: Why would you want to call `doSomething()` more than once? It's always going to return the same `Unit`. ;)

Comment: So the short answer to the question is: no.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could easily define one as an extension method:

```
scala> implicit def intWithTimes(n: Int) = new {        
     |   def times(f: => Unit) = 1 to n foreach {_ => f}
     | }
intWithTimes: (n: Int)java.lang.Object{def times(f: => Unit): Unit}

scala> 5 times {
     |   println("Hello World")
     | }
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Comment: I would love to have "times" added to RichInt.

Comment: It was actually added (https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/18599/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/runtime/RichInt.scala), but shortly after removed (https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/18648/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/runtime/RichInt.scala). Quoth extempore: "It was the best of times... it was the reversion of times...". Adding stuff to the standard library can break existing code, it has to be done fairly cautiously.

Comment: That is really interesting. Is 2.8 not already breaking backwards compatibility? I think in that case someone missed the opportunity to add such a method. It boils down to people writing that code over and over again because there is a usecase for it. You could just name it different like "5 iterationsOf x" or "5 repetitionsOf x".

Comment: Joa: you may google up much discussion, including this precise idea.

Answer (score 46):

The Range class has a foreach method on it that I think is just what you need. For example, this:

```
 (1 to 5).foreach(println)
```

produces

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5

Comment: Alternatively: `7 to 11 foreach { println(_) }`

Comment: `0 to 5 foreach println` looks cleaner.

Answer (score 22):

With [scalaz 5](http://scalaz.org):

```
doSomething.replicateM[List](n)
```

With [scalaz 6](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/823022500cb068d3e26cd2dfee8c0a05164b3ff4/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/IntW.scala):

```
n times doSomething
```

And that works as you would expect with most types (more precisely, for **every monoid**):

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._; import effects._;
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import effects._

scala> 5 times "foo"
res0: java.lang.String = foofoofoofoofoo

scala> 5 times List(1,2)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)

scala> 5 times 10
res2: Int = 50

scala> 5 times ((x: Int) => x + 1).endo
res3: scalaz.Endo[Int] = <function1>

scala> res3(10)
res4: Int = 15

scala> 5 times putStrLn("Hello, World!")
res5: scalaz.effects.IO[Unit] = scalaz.effects.IO$$anon$2@36659c23

scala> res5.unsafePerformIO
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

You could also say `doSomething replicateM_ 5` which only works if your `doSomething` is an idiomatic value (see `Applicative`). It has better type-safety, since you can do this:

```
scala> putStrLn("Foo") replicateM_ 5
res6: scalaz.effects.IO[Unit] = scalaz.effects.IO$$anon$2@8fe8ee7
```

but not this:

```
scala> { System.exit(0) } replicateM_ 5
<console>:15: error: value replicateM_ is not a member of Unit
```

Let me see you pull that off in Ruby.

Comment: Very cool... I didn't know scalaz had an IO monad... in practice do you find this to be worth the effort in scala?

Comment: It looks like `5 times 10` is arbitrarily choosing to sequence using the (0,+) monoid, which makes sense since in english we interpret "5 times 10" to mean 50... could you override it to use (1,*) and get exponentiation?

Comment: pelotom: To get 2^24, you might write: `24 times (2 ∏)`

Comment: Ah, but at the northeast Scala symposium you said you usually don't use IO monads... because you don't do much IO.

Comment: I'm doing a bit of IO these days, and I do it in a monad.

Comment: @Apocalisp I don't always do IO, but when I do, I do it in a monad

Comment: Any chance block could terminate execution early?

Comment: Can you do it with scalaz 7?

Comment: Seems like this has disappeared in scala 7, is there any alternative?

Comment: @SamDeMeyer `replicateM_` is still there

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of anything in the library. You can define a utility implicit conversion and class that you can import as needed.

```
class TimesRepeat(n:Int) {
  def timesRepeat(block: => Unit): Unit = (1 to n) foreach { i => block }
}
object TimesRepeat {
  implicit def toTimesRepeat(n:Int) = new TimesRepeat(n)
}

import TimesRepeat._

3.timesRepeat(println("foo"))
```

Rahul just posted a similar answer while I was writing this...

Answer (score 2):

It can be as simple as this:

```
scala> def times(n:Int)( code: => Unit ) {
          for (i <- 1 to n) code
       }
times: (n: Int)(code: => Unit)Unit

scala> times(5) {println("here")}
here
here
here
here
here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def times(f: => Unit)(cnt:Int) :Unit = {
  List.fill(cnt){f}
}
```

Comment: Although the code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.