# Most elegant repeat loop in Scala

Tags: scala, loops, coding-style

I'm looking for an equivalent of:

```
for(_ <- 1 to n)
  some.code()
```

that would be shortest and most elegant. Isn't there in Scala anything similar to this?

```
rep(n)
  some.code()
```

This is one of the most common constructs after all.

PS

I know it's easy to implement rep, but I'm looking for something predefined.

Comment: Basically, you're looking for the equivalent to Ruby's/Smalltalk's `42.times do some_thing end`, right? I mean "equivalent" not only in the sense of functionality, but also in syntactic "lightweightness".

Comment: Elegant is a subjective criteria.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
1 to n foreach { _ => some.code() }
```

Comment: Does this have any advantages (performace, style) over the way mentioned in the question?

Comment: @benroth No. In fact, `for (_ <- 1 to n) some.code()` is _translated_ into `1 to n foreach { _ => some.code() }` during compilation.

Comment: I am not convinced that is elegant.  Does the 1 to n constructor not create a sequence before the foreach is called?  What is the memory overhead if n = 65000?

Comment: @Willem It creates a sequence, of type `Range`. A `Range` has a constant memory size, regardless of start and end. There are performance problems with it, but they are way more subtle than this.

Answer (score 20):

You can create a helper method

```
def rep[A](n: Int)(f: => A) { if (n > 0) { f; rep(n-1)(f) } }
```

and use it:

```
rep(5) { println("hi") }
```

Based on @Jörgs comment I have written such a times-method:

```
class Rep(n: Int) {
  def times[A](f: => A) { loop(f, n) }
  private def loop[A](f: => A, n: Int) { if (n > 0) { f; loop(f, n-1) } }
}
implicit def int2Rep(i: Int): Rep = new Rep(i)

// use it with
10.times { println("hi") }
```

Based on @DanGordon comments, I have written such a times-method:

```
implicit class Rep(n: Int) {
    def times[A](f: => A) { 1 to n foreach(_ => f) } 
}

// use it with
10.times { println("hi") }
```

Comment: And get stack overflow when `n` is large. Just like this site is named :)

Comment: It may be tail-recursion optimized by compiler, though. But I wouldn't rely on that in real-world programming (e.g. some day I we may want logging at the tail).

Comment: You could make this much simpler by declaring the class with the `implicit` keyword. In fact, you wouldn't even need to have the explicit implicit conversion, or the first method in the `Rep` class.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest something like this:

```
List.fill(10)(println("hi"))
```

There are other ways, e.g.:

```
(1 to 10).foreach(_ => println("hi"))
```

Thanks to Daniel S. for the correction.

Answer (score 10):

With scalaz 6:

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._; import effects._;
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import effects._

scala> 5 times "foo"
res0: java.lang.String = foofoofoofoofoo

scala> 5 times List(1,2)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)

scala> 5 times 10
res2: Int = 50

scala> 5 times ((x: Int) => x + 1).endo
res3: scalaz.Endo[Int] = <function1>

scala> res3(10)
res4: Int = 15

scala> 5 times putStrLn("Hello, World!")
res5: scalaz.effects.IO[Unit] = scalaz.effects.IO$$anon$2@36659c23

scala> res5.unsafePerformIO
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

[ Snippet copied from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842540/is-there-a-brief-syntax-for-executing-a-block-n-times-in-scala/5501387#5501387) ]

Comment: How is `times` in-fix like that? Is that an advanced hack?