# Implicit Classes in Scala

Tags: scala

Below is the example program for Scala Implicit Class:

```
object Run {
   implicit class IntTimes(x: Int) {
      def times [A](f: =>A): Unit = {
         def loop(current: Int): Unit =

         if(current > 0){
            f
            loop(current - 1)
         }
         loop(x)
      }
   }
}
```

There is an other class that calls " `4 times println("hello")`" as following, but I can not understand " `4 times println("hello")`"  mean?

```
object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      4 times println("hello")
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842540/is-there-a-brief-syntax-for-executing-a-block-n-times-in-scala

Comment: can this be called like  ' times(4) println("hello") '

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`4 times println("hello")` roughly translates into:

```
val c = new IntTimes(4)
c.times(println("hello"))
```

That is, since there is an implicit class that takes an `Int` as its only argument, with a method `times`, doing `4.times` implicitly instantiates the class with 4 as argument, and then invokes `times` on it.

Answer (score 6):

I also found this example way overly complicated to demonstrate Implicit Classes.

In a nutshell Implicit Classes overwrite other classes with new methods and properties.

In this example, it is overwriting Int to give it a method times.
The times method takes a call-by-name parameter with a generic return type:

```
def times [A](f: =>A): Unit
```

Means f is a function that returns a generic type A.

When a call-by-name variable is used, it calls the function and becomes the return value.
Inside times method it is using recursion to loop the call of f the number of times the integer it's called on.

In scala you can call methods by using a dot or space, and no need for brackets for parameters, 
so `object.method(param1, param2)` could be `object method param1 param2`

Hence the final call `4 times println("hello")`
is actually `4.times(println("hello"))`

Comment: I am little confused here. I see that the method "times" takes a functional argument which does not take any input and returns A as output. But in the invocation of "times", the function println is passed which takes a string as i/p and returns Unit. This is just opposite to the signature. But this is working. Can someone please help me to understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is useful to see that f has a call by name semantics so evaluation of f is delayed until the actual execution of the line in the body which calls f. The braces for the function body of `loop` have been skipped to show the body contains only the if statement. So, the method `times` just defines `loop` and calls it once.